# Django Queryset only() and defer()

Tags: django, django-models

In the real world, how often do people use QuerySet methods like `defer()` and `only()`? 
I guess I handnt really heard much about them and only recently have I came across these methods.

See Docs here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: This is my first time to hear that and thanks for the info.

Comment: It's often useful when writing data migrations (using `migrations.RunPython`), these are pretty handy and can avoid a lot of back-and-forth when running migrations for a big DB table in production.

Comment: Came here bcoz they asked in interview ;)

Comment: Almost always use some of these, select_related, prefetch_related, defer, and only when I need to retrieve lots of rows. Select_related, prefetch_related is mainly to fix n+1 query problem wile defer and only is to avoid loading to much data like text fields when not needed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These methods are mostly of use when optimizing performance of your application.

Generally speaking, if you are not having performance problems, you don't need to optimize.  And if you don't need to optimize, you don't need these functions.  This is a case with a lot of advanced `QuerySet` features, such as `select_related` or `prefetch_related`.

As for "how often they are used in the real world", that isn't really an answerable question.  They are used when they're needed.  If you don't need them, don't use them.

Answer (score 29):

`defer()` and `only()` are somewhat opposite of each other. Both receives list of `field_names`. `defer()` will not query, list of columns, passed to it as argument. On Contrary to it, `only()` will query, only list of columns, passed to it as argument.

Both are used in a scenario, where

- you want either optimization, by avoiding unnecessary column fetching
- you are implementing views in your python code. Eg.Admin have to
  shown X no. of cols, User have to be shown Y no. of cols, Visitor
  have to be shown z no of cols.

Answer (score 0):

I have occasionally found pretty dramatic speedups by using `defer` and `only` to avoid fetching TextFields in particular from the database. It's not supposed to happen according to Django's docs, but the speedup is often hundreds of milliseconds or more. However, I only do this when there's a performance issue to begin with, and when I'm 100% sure I will never need those fields.